# JPA CriteriaBuilder subquery?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
select * FROM T1
WHERE 
0 = ( SELECT count(*) FROM T2 WHERE T2.T1ObjId = T1.ObjId AND T2.column = 'someText' )
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to write it using the JPA 2.0 Specification system.

I can't even figure out where to start with the query. I have a class that implements `Specification<T1>` and implements the `toPredicate()` method. I can't figure out where to go from there.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T1")
public class Table1
{
   @Column(name = "ObjId")
   public Long objId;

   // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T2")
public class Table2
{
   @Column(name = "T1ObjId")
   public Long objId;

   @Column(name = "column")
   public String clmn;

   // ...
}
```

you can try to use something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Table1> criteria = builder.createQuery(Table1.class);

Root<Table1> t1 = criteria.from(Table1.class);
Subquery<Long> sq = criteria.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Table2> t2 = sq.from(Table2.class);

ParameterExpression<String> clmnParameter = builder.parameter(String.class);
sq.select(builder.count(t2))
  .where(
     builder.equal(t2.get("objId"), t1.get("objId")),
     builder.equal(t2.get("clmn"), clmnParameter)
  );
criteria.select(t1);
criteria.where(builder.equal(sq, 0L));

TypedQuery<Table1> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
query.setParameter(clmnParameter, "someText");
List<Table1> result = query.getResultList();
```

P.S. I would suggest you to read an excellent book - *Java Persistence
with Hibernate* (see *15.5 Subselects* in second edition of this book)